# What type of path is NMSSH looking for (iOS)?

Tags: ios, linux, path

I have established an SSH connection with a remote server, and would like to check if there is a directory in the user's home folder called "Images", and create that directory if there isn't. I know I must be doing something wrong with the path here, but I can't figure out what:

```
NMSFTP *sftp = [[NMSFTP alloc] initWithSession:session];
    if (![sftp directoryExistsAtPath:@"~/Images"]) {
        [sftp createDirectoryAtPath:@"~/Images"];
    }
```

Here is the output the debugger is giving me:

```
NMSSH: Could not open file at path ~/Images (Error 0: )
```

The instance of NMSSHSession connects and authenticates just fine, it's the path I'm not sure about. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the implementation of the two methods being used:

```
- (BOOL)directoryExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path {
    LIBSSH2_SFTP_HANDLE *handle = [self openFileAtPath:path flags:LIBSSH2_FXF_READ mode:0];

    if (!handle) {
        return NO;
    }

    LIBSSH2_SFTP_ATTRIBUTES fileAttributes;
    int rc = libssh2_sftp_fstat(handle, &fileAttributes);
    libssh2_sftp_close(handle);

    return rc == 0 && LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_ISDIR(fileAttributes.permissions);
}

- (BOOL)createDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path {
    int rc = libssh2_sftp_mkdir(self.sftpSession, [path UTF8String],
                                LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IRWXU|
                                LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IRGRP|LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IXGRP|
                                LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IROTH|LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IXOTH);

    return rc == 0;
}
```

SOLUTION: It turns out you must also call connect on the instance of NMSFTP (as well as the instance of NMSSHSession) in order for it to work. This code works properly:

```
NMSFTP *sftp = [[NMSFTP alloc] initWithSession:session];
[sftp connect];
if (![sftp directoryExistsAtPath:@"Images"]) {
    [sftp createDirectoryAtPath:@"Images"];
}
```

Comment: You should be in the user's home directory when you log in. So try using just `@"Images"` as the path.

Comment: @rmaddy You do start in the home directory yes. I tried just `@"Images"` as well, but that gives the same error:

Comment: Is there documentation for this `NMSFTP` class? What does it say about the `createDirectoryAtPath:` method?

Comment: @rmaddy The documentation for the class is [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/NMSSH/2.0.0/Classes/NMSFTP.html). It unfortunately isn't very specific about how the path should look. I'll edit my post to include the implementation of the method.

Comment: The docs for `libssh2_sftp_mkdir_ex` state: "path - full path of the new directory to create. Note that the new directory's parents must all exist priot to making this call."

Comment: @AdamM. the path should looks like this `@"/var/www/foo/bar/"`

Comment: Thank you for the input, the full path of the directory I want to create (using my own user account on OS X) is `@"/Users/adammurnane/Images/"`. However, this still produces the same error: `NMSSH: Could not open file at path /Users/adammurnane/Images/ (Error 0: )`

Comment: I figured out the problem. There is a method in `NMSFTP` called `connect:` that must first be called, in addition to calling `connect:` on the instance of `NMSSHSession`. I'll edit my question to provide more detail.